# Unable to insert values in hive table using beeline

Tags: hadoop, hive, thrift

I have connected to hive using thrift server. And, I am using beeline for querying the tables.

I am able to see the existing tables, and able to perform select/aggregate on these tables.

I am also able to create the tables and databases, but when I am trying to INSERT VALUES in the table, I am getting the following error:

```
15/08/10 13:02:32 WARN ThriftCLIService: Error executing statement:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveQl$ParseException: Failed to parse: **insert into table test values("kundan")**
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation.run(Shim13.scala:192)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:231)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:218)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:79)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.access$000(HiveSessionProxy.java:37)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1.run(HiveSessionProxy.java:64)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.doAs(HadoopShimsSecure.java:493)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy.invoke(HiveSessionProxy.java:60)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.executeStatementAsync(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:233)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:344)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1313)
```

Comment: Please give more details, e.g. your definition of table `test`.

Comment: Below is the schema of the test table :



                        

 col_name  : name
data_type : varchar(64)

Comment: Please give the complete `CREATE TABLE` definition and also which version of Hive you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In Hive it is not possible to insert values directly into a hive table you can do it in 3 ways

1. You can insert values from one table into another table using insert command.

**For ex:**

```
   INSERT INTO TABLE tablename1 [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)] 
select_statement1 FROM from_statement;
```

2.Loading data into table using input file from hdfs or from local location.

**For ex:**

```
LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INPATH 'filepath' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE tablename [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)];
```

3.Loading data into table while creating the table itself using the input file.

**For ex:**

```
CREATE TABLE 'table name'(fields) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '<hdfs_location>';
```

Comment: It definitely is possible to insert into a hive table.

Comment: Hi  @Marcin, By using common sence we can say that insert query would work.but  this answer is correct.by default we cannot insert data using insert query in **thrift server** of apache spark.Please post if you have answer.

Comment: @Satyanarayana.Ruppa Check out this whole section of the docs on inserting: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries